# Return values of common elements giving two dict

Tags: dictionary

I have been trying to get my head around this function that takes two dict{}, and get the common values of a key, Value pair, which in turn shall be pass to a function f() which shall be define out side the function:

I tried something this:

```
def dicts_interdiff( d1, d2 ) :
    dict1 = dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : k in d2 and d2[k] == v, d1.items()))
    dict2 = dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : k not in d1 and d1[k] != v, d2.items()))
    return dict1, dict2
```

I passed this to it this test:

```
d1 = {'1':10, '2':20, '3':30, '4':40}
d2 = {'1':10, '4':40, '5':50, '6':60}

result = dicts_interdiff(d1,d2)
print(result)
```

this is the output:

```
({}, {'1': 10, '3': 30, '2': 20, '5': 50, '4': 40, '6': 60})
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you don't get a error message when you use `k not in d1 and d1[k] != v`.

```
def dicts_interdiff( d1, d2 ) :
    dict1 = dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : k in d2 and d2[k] == v, d1.items()))
    dict2 = dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : k not in d1 or d1[k] != v, d2.items()))
    return dict1, dict2
```

and use your d1,d2 will return `({'1':10,'4':40},{'5':50,'6':60})`

Comment: That was close: but not returning all the diffs element `{'2':20, '3':30,}`

Comment: add a return: `dict3 = dict(filter(lambda (k,v) : k not in d2 or d2[k] != v, d1.items()))`. Or else, if you have '3':30 in d1 and '3':300 in d2, it can't show the difference.

Comment: That was super! Then I updated `dict2.update(dict3)` so I only return dict1 and dict2. Thank you

Comment: If use `update`, some key may be overwrited. You can try `d1 = {'1':10, '2':20, '3':30, '4':40}` and `d2 = {'1':10,'3':300, '4':40, '5':50, '6':60}`.

Comment: Yes your right, Where `'3':30` and `'3':300'` there is problem